# Extract Duplicates MySQL Cross-table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for a query to extract specific information from two different tables that have duplicates i.e.

```
Table 1;
Columns [x] [y]

Table 2;
Columns [a] [b]
```

If `[b]` from `Table2` matches `[y]` from `Table1` then `extract` `[x]` from `Table1` and `[a]` from `Table2`

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT Table1.x, Table2.a
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table2.b = Table1.y;
```

This seems too simple, am I missing something?

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that. :x